# Understanding the correlations in pairplots

Tags: correlation, python, data-visualization

I was using pairplots and I'm stuck in understanding the pair wise relation between those features that have vertical or horizontal lines in the pair plots.

(Image source - [source](http://gael-varoquaux.info/interpreting_ml_tuto/content/02_why/01_interpreting_linear_models.html))

[image]

The correlation between say experience and age is pretty clear. I'm trying to interpret feature 'sex' with other features like 'age', 'education' etc. which shows horizontal/vertical lines at two distinct values. Also, help me understand the plot between 'wage' and 'experience', 'education' and 'age' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason you're seeing horizontal or vertical lines is because "Sex" is variable which takes only two values "0" and "1". The horizontal dots at Sex==0 represent one gender and the dots at Sex==1 represent the other one.

You could set "Sex" as categorical datatype and use boxplots to observe wages, education distribution among different sexes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so, is it like there is no defined correlation between 'sex' containing two categories and 'wage'....as for a given wage value there seem to have both categories of sex? but I liked your suggestion of looking category wise correlation...thanks

Comment: Sure there's a correlation.  Why do you think not?  Just apply the usual formulas.  The main problem here is that this form of plotting makes it difficult to *see* the amount of correlation.  You can improve on it in many ways, such as by using semitransparency, jittering, and superimposing graphs of (say) least squares fits, robust smooths, covariance ellipses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical and horizontal lines are there because one of those variables are categorial. For eg, in the bottom left image; sex vs wage, sex can only be 0 or 1, while wage does not have an upper bound.